# Why can't i save registered users to the database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

So i have been trying to resolve this issue for a while now, with no awail. Everything works but when i try to login with a "succesfully registered user", it still shows invalid credentials, meaning that the save didn't succeed,

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SchoolManagementApplication
{
    public partial class LoginDialog : Form
    {
        public LoginDialog()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool VerifyUserCredentials(string username, string password)
        {
            bool isValidUser = false;

            // Connection string
            string connectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.UnPConnectionString;

            // SQL query
            string query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Table2] WHERE Username = @Username AND Password = @Password";

            // Create a new connection
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                // Create a new command
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    // Add parameters to the query
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                    // Open the connection
                    connection.Open();
                    // Execute the query
                    int result = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
                    // Check if the result is greater than 0
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        isValidUser = true;
                    }
                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            return isValidUser;
        }

        public void AddUser(string username, string password)
        {
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\\Users\\shayan.homaiesfahan\\Desktop\\SchoolManagementApplication\\SchoolManagementApplication\\bin\\Debug\\Unp.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                // insert the new user into the table
                string insertSql = "INSERT INTO [Table2] (Username, Password) VALUES (@Username, @Password)";
                using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertSql, connection))
                {
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", username);
                    insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", password);
                    insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        private void BtnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Get the entered username and password
            string username = tbxUsername.Text;
            string password = tbxPassword.Text;

            // Verify the user credentials
            if (VerifyUserCredentials(username, password))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Welcome: {0}", username));
                // Code to open the main application goes here
                this.Hide();
                MainInterface MI = new MainInterface();
                MI.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid credentials. Please try again.");
                //// Clear the textboxes
                tbxUsername.Text = "";
                tbxPassword.Text = "";
            }
        }


        private void Btn_register_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string username = tbxUsername.Text;
            string password = tbxPassword.Text;

            // Verify that the username and password are not empty
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                // Call the AddUser method
                AddUser(username, password);

                // Show a message that the user has been registered
                MessageBox.Show("You have been successfully registered!");

                // Clear the textboxes
                tbxUsername.Text = "";
                tbxPassword.Text = "";
            }
            else
            {
                // Show a message that the username and password are required
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password are required.");
            }
        }

        private void btnCancel2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

It did work in one point, but somehow it stopped working.

Comment: Maybe you have different connection strings?

Comment: BTW: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your next troubleshooting step is to look at the table's contents. Use SSMS or some other client. Did your INSERT succeed?

Comment: You're connecting to a database file stored inside `bin\Debug` that will be overwritten on every build. Either specify a different path or don't use `AttachDbFilename` at all. You're already using SQL Server Express which means you can create a proper database and connect to it by its name.